# How active autocomplete in the windows shell?

Tags: python, windows

I am a beginner in python and I would like to be able to autocomplete without having to be writing the methods in the windows shell.

How do I show the methods the variable when I put a point?

Answer (score 1):

Install [ipython](https://ipython.org/install.html) and use that in the cmd prompt.

My screenshot is in MacOS but it should be pretty similar on Windows.

[image]

On windows:

```
pip install ipython
```

then `ipython.exe` can be found in `scripts` directory of python installation.